# Getting multiple values from HTML select/listbox

Tags: php, html

This is my current code setup:

```
if(isset($_POST['dobtn'])){
    foreach($_POST['selnums'] as $num){
        echo $num."<br>";
    }
}
```

And my select setup is like this:

```
<form action="" type="POST">
<select name="selnums[]" multiple size="15">
<optgroup label=randomnamehere><option value=valuehere>namehere</option></optgroup>
</select>
</form>
```

Why am I not getting any values back?

Is there something I am like missing that is obvious?

Comment: I don't see the button, `dobtn`, in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that looks for the `selnum` array values is conditional on `$_POST['dobtn']` being set. There is no such input (presumably a button) in your form. If that's the real code, then that would definitely be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `method="post"`, not `type`.

Plus: I would get rid of the `optgroup` for testing. And some arguments are missing quotes.

Finally: Why don't you try something simple to see if your form works at all?: `<input name="foo">`. And in PHP: `echo $_POST['foo']`. If that doesn't work, there's a general problem in your form, unrelated to the `select`.

Comment: Even so, wouldn't the value submitted be part of the array `selnums`?